# Two questions on rotation matrices and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ satisfy the relations:
\begin{align*}
(Id_{3}+A)(Id_{3}-A)^{-1} = B\ &\Longleftrightarrow(Id_{3}+A)=B(Id_{3}-A)\\ 
&\Longleftrightarrow\ A = (B+Id_{3})^{-1}(B-Id_{3}).
\end{align*}

1. Show that $B+id_{3}$ will always be invertible except when $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.
2. Show that if $B$ is a rotation and has $-1$ as an eigenvalue then $B$ is a rotation of $\pi$ radians on some axis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for 1: what does invertibility of a matrix mean in terms of its eigenvalues?

Hint for 2: use whatever definition you have seen of a rotation.

Comment: @Justpasingby $A$ in invertible iff $0$ not is a eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Correct. Doesn't that allow you to solve the first question?

Comment: $B+I_3$ is invertible iff $0$ is not eigenvalue of $B+I_3$ iff $\det(B+I_3-0I_3)\neq 0$ iff $\det(B+I_3)\neq 0$ but how obtain that $\det(B-I_3)=0$?

Comment: For question 1 you do not need the latter determinant, shall we consider that question solved? For question 2 you should tell me what your definition of a rotation is.

Comment: I shoewd questions 1. You know a rotation is any direction in $\mathbb{R}^3$?